# Handle exception "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference" on ko.observable field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I'm using Knockoutjs on a registration form. I have runtime error when user click button to show password field

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined
>   or null reference

how to handle runtime exception in KO.js?

```
   self.showHidePasswordField = function () {

        if (self.password1().length > 0 || typeof self.password1().length !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('show');
        } else {
            console.log('hide');
        }

    };
```

Comment: Assuming you are sure you defined the password1 observable you can try `if (self.password1() != null && typeof self.password1().length !== 'undefined')`

Comment: thank.it  works. can you make your comments as answer and I will make it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are sure you defined the `password1` observable, you can try the following:

```
if (self.password1() != null && typeof self.password1().length !== 'undefined')
```